# Check if email exist using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Basically, I want to check if the email exists in the DB automatically. The function will not work when `connection.php` & `mysqli` queries was inserted.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="email" name="email" class="formEmail">
```

**JS:**

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.formEmail').on('change', function() {
        //ajax request
        $.ajax({
            url: "queries/checkEmail.php",
            data: {
                'email' : $('.formEmail').val()
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                if(date == true) {
                    alert('Email exists!');
                }
                else {
                    alert('Email doesnt!');
                }
            },
            error: function(data){
                //error
            }
        });
    });
  });
```

**PHP:**

```
require_once("../connection.php");

$userEmail = $_GET['email'];

$checkEmail=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT email from accounts WHERE email='$userEmail'");

if (mysqli_num_rows($checkEmail) == 1) {
  $response = true;
} else {
  $response = false;
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: `data !== date`

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for the help. I changed the date to data but still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a small mistake in getting the response in the `if` condition in the success block of `ajax` call function.

> Rewrite `date` to `data` in if condition

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.formEmail').on('change', function() {
        //ajax request
        $.ajax({
            url: "queries/checkEmail.php",
            data: {
                'email' : $('.formEmail').val()
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                if(data == true) {
                    alert('Email exists!');
                }
                else {
                    alert('Email doesnt!');
                }
            },
            error: function(data){
                //error
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: you also use 'keyup()' function to dynamically check the hit server and check for the email

Comment: Thanks for the help. I changed the date to data but still not working.

Comment: post your "error msg" here, i ll help you to get through this issue. you might wanna call JQuery script before your AJAX call function.

Answer (score 0):

When you use ajax and your output is in JSON, you need to send pure JSON output only, Please check the below code. I have added header of the JSON message inside checkEmail.php file, so It can be easily read by the javascript

**Code**

```
<?php
require_once("../connection.php");

$userEmail = $_GET['email'];

$checkEmail=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT email from accounts WHERE email='$userEmail'");

if (mysqli_num_rows($checkEmail) == 1) {
  $response = true;
} else {
  $response = false;
}

//Here your required to set the header which will make output as pure JSON output and easy to read by javascript

header('Content-Type:application/json;');
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Did you test this? Still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add request method in Ajax: `type:'post'`
And of course fix in PHP: change `GET` to `POST`